# Simple adapter not loading all the images

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code to show images from url in list view so im using this class that extended from simpleAdapter

```
    package com.mypackage.lebadagency;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(v, value);   
}

}
```

and using it is like :

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(
                    EconomyPanel.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.economy_list_item, new String[] {TAG_ID, TAG_IMAGE_URL,TAG_NAME 
                     }, new int[] {R.id.idTV, R.id.image1,
                    R.id.name });
            setListAdapter(adapter);


        }
```

my list load 10 items, my problem is that it does not load all the 10 images , sometimes it only loads one of them , what is the problem and how to fix it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with this code , this code is working no need to change the method of viewing the image or anything the problem is simpler than that , any image that contain space gab in its file name , the browsers can handle it by replacing the space with %20 , and when android retrieve the image url it retrieve it without the 20% symbol , so i need to add this command to the url :

```
value=value.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

and then

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(v, value);
```